# cant send response after setting status

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, formidable

i have made a route in my express that processes a form when it submits .
i am trying to set a status and send a response to client when the form process faces an error or problem .
i am using [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) in the front-End and [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) in the back-end .
here is how i am trying to handle errors in the methods call back :

```
if (err) {
      res.status(500) // i have tried different status-codes !
      .send(`error on parsing : ${err}`)
      .end();      
}
```

the problem is :
1_ **if i set most of status codes ( almost all of them except 200 ) then i get an response says Request failed with status code 500 (or other codes i set) and the data sent by .send() method is not received in the client-side**

2_ **.send() with or without .end() does not stop rest of code to be executed , as i am trying to end response in call backs if they face error , else at the end a 200 status-code is sent , codes execute till end and reach the end and it tries to again set status and i get error cant set headers when they are sent to the client**

i have tried to set status code with different methods or send response in other ways .
i searched the web , and i found out the correct way is res.status().send() and i am doing correctly , however i am facing problem .

here is my code (if you need i can paste full code) :

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.on("error", err => {
    if (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send(`Error on formidable : ${err}`)
        .end();
        console.log('continued');
    }
  });


  form.encoding = "utf8";
  form.uploadDir = "./uploadedFiles/";
  form.maxFileSize = 2000 * 1024 * 1024;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {

      res.status(500)
      .send(`error on parsing : ${err}`)
      .end();

    }
 // code continues with same style , methods with error handling in call backs  
//at the end of code :  
res.status(200).send("form successfully Submitted !");
}
```

"getting response" part of Client-side code :

```
try {
      let response = await axios.post("/upload", FD, {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      });
      console.log(response);

      $("#res")
        .css("display", "block")
        .text(response.data);
      $("#spinnerbox").css("display", "none");
    } catch (error) {
      $("#res")
        .css("display", "block")
        .text(error);
      console.log("Catched Error");
    }
```

i expect when i set a status i be able to send a response as well . ( as i searched res.status().send() should be correct ) .
i would appreciate your helps .

Answer (score 1):

your best solution is to use try and catch block then throw new error
and create error middleware then you can set the status code and call next with the error

```js
app.get('/route', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // do something
    if ('something failed') {
      throw new Error('error message!');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

// or if you want to set the status code

app.get('/route', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // do something
    if ('something failed') {
      res.status(500);
      const error = new Error('error message!');
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welome to SO, the answer looks good but it's important to have quality in our code standards. You should edit to add in the tabs/spaces to make the code readable. Remember only submit an answer you'd be happy to commit to production on your own codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a response with `.josn` too.

**200**

```
return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'SUCCESS' });
```

**400**

```
return res.status(400).json({ error: 'ERROR' });
```

In your instance you got error 
**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client**

It's come when your server returns multiple responses of a single request
Ex.

```
// Incorrect Example
if(something) {
  res.status(200).json({ msg: 'SUCCESS' }); 
} 
 res.status(400).json({ error: 'ERROR' });
```

In the above code, once a condition full-filled then it gives `200` and In other case it will give `400`, Si here 2 times response send which occurs such error (**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client** )

To avoid such error you need to add a keyword `return` before response.

```
// Correct Example
if(something) {
 return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'SUCCESS' }); 
} 
return res.status(400).json({ error: 'ERROR' });
```

Comment: with the way you explained , in the client side , it heads to the error in Try Catch statement , i get this message in the catch block :  Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: Above explantation is for nodeJs only

Comment: i am using nodeJS and express , getting result by axios asynchronously

Comment: I suggest first add proper error handling from  backend  then go for client side

Comment: i am trying this now :      
 return res
        .status(500)
        .json({msg:`error on parsing : ${err}`}).end();
actually , no response in sent after status is sent , how ever if status be 200 or ... , status and response are both sent , is it possible status code stop the rest of response ?

Comment: You don't need to add `.end()` after `.json()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198138/discussion-between-imanemadi-and-neel-rathod).

Comment: Yes some of code contains no body...it means no body will be sent over that status code like 204.